# Storing less than- and greater than-signs (<, >) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have data with values (decimal) including less than-signs (<, in theory it could also be greater than-signs (>)). This data comes from scientific analysis and represent values that are below the detection value. 
My question is which is the best way to store those values in a mysql database. Is the only option to add a new column which has true or false, depending if it is a less than value or not?

So instead of using one column

```
|value|   
|   <2|   
|  2.1|
```

I have to add a column:

```
|less_than|value|   
|true  |   2|   
|false |  2.1|
```

And then in output deal with the true/false-column to get the <-sign back?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whether you store it as a boolean or as a `char(1)` to simply hold the `<` or null, I would _not_ store it in the same column as a the numeric value. If `value` is typically a number, it belongs in a truly numeric column type or you will be forever fighting against type casing and string manipulations when attempting to do arithmetic on it or produce aggregates.

Comment: Another possibility would be to store the detection value in another column and do comparisons at query time to determine if `value` is greater or less than the threshold value.

Comment: Let's see the `SELECT` before commenting.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!

Sorry! Off course I forgot to remove the last <-sign in the second table in the question. Took it out now. 

Anyhow, judging from you comments,  I conclude that there is no better way than to use another column for values below detection limit.

Comment: Yes sounds like two columns is the way to go here. I'd make the other column a char field holding either '>' or '<' or '='. (And if you need it some day, you can even store '≤' or '≥' or '≈'.) You should have a constraint of course to allow only valid signs.